CreateSymbolicLink succeeds in Windows 10 Home but fails in Windows 10 Professional
CreateSymbolicLink succeeds in Windows 10 Home but fails in Windows 10 Professional. My acocunt is in the admins group with UAC enabled.
Similarly,
c:\dir> mklink a b

in Home Edition it succeeds. But in Professional Edition it fails with message 'You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.'
Windows version is [Version 10.0.19045.4651].
I also tried SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE flag (introduced in Windows 10 1703, v10.0.14972) in the CreateSymbolicLink API, but this also fails in my Professional Edition + my account with code 1314 (A required privilege is not held by the client.). Why and how to solve it?


Why vote down? I don't think this question should go to superuser.com. Creating symbolic link should be available to all users, not just super users

MSDN Docs state for SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE: Developer Mode must first be enabled on the machine before this option will function.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinkw

@Remko This will allow installation from any source and I don't want to enable it. My solution is adding my account to the privileged list in the group policy editor

1314 (0x522) ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD: A required privilege is not held by the client.
It means that you don't have the privilege. Under some versions of the system, it may be necessary to explicitly request certain permissions.
I suggest you could try to use lookupPrivilegeValue with SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege to set the user right to create symbolic links.
Refer to the Doc:Create symbolic links

#define SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_PRIVILEGE (35L) from wdm.h. So not need call LookupPrivilegeValue - it is well known
